# Componente Calendar 'Ext.calendar.panel.Panel' EXTJs

Tags: calendar, extjs

Olá,

Eu estou tentando utilizar o componente calendar do ExtJs 6.7 porem estou com algumas dificuldades quanto ao calendar-form-add.

Ele é chamado a partir do evento de um createButton, onde o painel é aberto.

O componente traz algumas configurações que eu não estou conseguindo alterar, como por exemplo a linguagem, que esta em inglês, e preciso mostrar em português.

Ja procurei em toda documentação, mas não consigo localizar uma forma de fazer as alterações que preciso.

Alguém ja teve algum problema parecido, ou saiba como posso chegar a esse componente, para fazer as alterações no layout dele?

Agradeço desde já a atenção.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).